# set permission for folders using c#

Tags: c#

I have written code to set permission for a folder using c# to be read-only. the code works fine and the access is denied for the current user. the issue now how to remove the security permissions for the same folder programmatically. even I had used the same code and give the user full privilege. I can't access the folder and access to the path is denied exception fired.

the below code used for set permission

```
DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
// Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the current security settings
DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
string User = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(User, FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Allow));
myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(User, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Deny));
//set the new access settings
myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
```

and this code used to allow modify on the folder

```
// Get directory access info
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dinfo.GetAccessControl();

// Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));

// Set the access control
dinfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. You first remove permissions on a folder, then you want to re-apply permissions ?

Comment: ...and what code did you use? E.g., did you use `WMI`, `SetAccessControl`, something else?

Comment: I updated the question, and include the codes snippet

Comment: Use `ModifyAccessRule` instead of `AddAccessRule`

Comment: It's still not entirely clear what you're trying to do (grant `Full Control` to `Everyone`, except `User` who just gets `Read`?) and what the problem is, but you are aware that if you `Deny` `Modify` for `User` and then `Allow` `Full Control` for `Everyone` that, for `User`, the `Deny` will override the `Allow`?

Comment: So if the directory is readonly for the current user, then the current user can't modify the permissions..?

Comment: so what is the right way to make folder read-only for the current user?

Comment: The issue would be that, since `Everyone` includes `User`, a permission for `User` and a permission for `Everyone` will both apply.  Instead of `Everyone` can you grant `Modify` to another group and simply not add `User` to it?  By the way, I think it'd be easier to get the permissions figured out using Explorer and, once you have those working, then write the code that produces those same permissions.

Comment: Also note that [`FileSystemRights.Modify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights#System_Security_AccessControl_FileSystemRights_Modify) _includes_ `FileSystemRights.Read`, so if you `Deny` `Modify` you are also `Deny`ing `Read`.  I generally try to avoid using `Deny` permissions if possible, but another approach would be to only `Deny` the `Modify` rights _other than_ `Read` (that is, `Deny` `Write | Delete`).